# IMG SRC tags and JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, image

Is it possible to call JavaScript function from the array IMG SRC tag to get the url image of more than one?

Like this:

```
var imgsBlocks = new Array( '/1.png', '/2.png', '/3.png');
function getImageUrl(elemid) {  
var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
document.getElementById("get_img").src=imgsBlocks[ind]; 
}
```

I tried to call with this:

```
<img src="'+imgsBlocks[2]+'" id="get_img"/>
```

or

```
<img src="'+imgsBlocks[3]+'" id="get_img"/>
```

it's not work?

Answer (score 0):

Please check either images exist in the same location that you are trying to assign. your code looks fine, initially you can verify by hard coding image url and see either it is shown on page or not e.g.

```
document.getElementById("get_img").src='/1.png';
```

as well as if image are located on same location of web page then you don't need to write a "/" , just write name of image i.e. "1.png"